# How to Group .xml Files to be Deserialized Together

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to serialize multiple forms using Mr. Yossu's code this link: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86503/Saving-the-state-serializing-a-Windows-Form

Mr.Yossu's Serialise method is: (There's also a private sub for adding children properties to the serialization.)

```
Public Shared Sub Serialise(c As Control, XmlFileName As String)
            Dim xmlSerialisedForm As New XmlTextWriter(XmlFileName, System.Text.Encoding.[Default])
            xmlSerialisedForm.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            xmlSerialisedForm.WriteStartDocument()
            xmlSerialisedForm.WriteStartElement("ChildForm")
            ' enumerate all controls on the form, and serialise them as appropriate
            AddChildControls(xmlSerialisedForm, c)
            xmlSerialisedForm.WriteEndElement()
            ' ChildForm
            xmlSerialisedForm.WriteEndDocument()
            xmlSerialisedForm.Flush()
            xmlSerialisedForm.Close()
        End Sub
```

Basically I just need to save all the forms to one file because it's a character sheet for D&D, and I needed more than one form to fit every entry.

I converted everything to Visual Basic and have the code working fine for a single form, but having multiple forms serialize to the same file via different lines of code obviously revealed some hangups. 
The code I'm using for serializing is:

```
FormSerialisation.FormSerialisor.Serialise(Me, SaveAsPath)
```

My question is how to either serialize multiple forms to the same xml file in the same line of code, such as

```
FormSerialisation.FormSerialisor.Serialise(Me AND Me2 AND Me3, SaveAsPath)
```

OR how to group xml files to all be deserialized when one of them is selected via OpenFile Dialog.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with multiple files? You're a bit at the mercy of how Mr. Yossu designed his helper. And without posting it here, it won't be possible to help you any further. Please add the definition of the `Serialise` method to your question.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with multiple files, I'd just like to simplify the process of opening a character so that the user doesn't have to open 5 files every time they open the application.

Comment: In spite of the description the code is not serializing forms or controls at all, just the key/main property for each.  It would be easier and less code to have a class or list of them for serializing and then use databinding to display the data